# Multiply each element of array by random number

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, for-loop

I am wondering if there any more efficient form of multiplying each element of array by random number (except a for loop)

```
import random
import numpy as np

A=np.array([[1,2,3],[3,4,5]])
B=np.ones_like(A)

random.seed(0)

for i in range(B.shape[0]):
  for j in range(B.shape[1]):
    B[i][j] = B[i][j]*random.randint(8, 12)
```

Comment: Why are you multiplying the array of 1's instead of the array with values?

Comment: you can make a random int array the same size as `B`, and do the normal array multiplication.  No need to do this element by element.

Comment: It is not necessarily an array of ones, in my task it would be an array with various numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Multiplying the random number by 1 is the same as just assigning the random number. So you could just use `numpy.random.randint` to create a random array with the same shape:

```
B = np.random.rand(8, 13, np.shape(A))
```